# How to verify if tmux is properly installed on Mac OSX

Tags: osx, software-installation, executable, tmux

I've just tried installing tmux from source (via installing libevent first). The installation seemed fine, without throwing any obvious error. But when I typed `tmux` in iTerm2, it returned "command not found". However, there is clearly an executable named `tmux` in `/opt/bin/`.

So I am a bit puzzled that whether I have successfully installed `tmux` on my mac. How do I get it work with iTerm2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `tmux` in a shell, the shell looks for an executable called `tmux` in one of the directories enumerated in the `PATH` variable (it's a colon-separated list of directories). Check if `/opt/bin` is in your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

If `/opt/bin` is not in your path, then either install tmux in a different directory that is in your path, or add `/opt/bin` to your path. The usual place to set the `PATH` variable is in `~/.profile`, or in `~/.bash_profile` if you have that but no `~/.profile`, or in `~/.zprofile` if your shell is zsh.

If `/opt/bin` is in your path, what's happening is that your shell is keeping the path contents in a cache in memory and not noticing the new addition. Run `hash -r` to rebuild the cache in this shell. Each shell instance builds its own cache, so you won't have this problem in shells that you start after the installation of tmux.

Comment: when you say install tmux in a different directory, do you mean simply moving the executable from `/opt/bin` to one of the directories that is on my path? Thanks.

Comment: @Simon Yes, or pass a different path for `make install` (setting whatever variable the makefile uses). Or you can make a symbolic link from `/opt/bin/tmux` to a directory in your path, but I recommend picking a method that won't require extra work for other software that you'll install manually in the future.

Comment: I'd suggest using Homebrew http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/ for managing command line tools like tmux and others. It handlers installation, updates, removal, etc, and tools are available immediately in the current PATH after installation.